Question about pyproject.toml and setup.py when deploying with github actions
alrighty so i'm encountering an error with my pyproject.toml (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aghastmuffin/spotify-cli/main/pyproject.toml)
and setup.py (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aghastmuffin/spotify-cli/main/setup.py)
during publish package (in my github actions, posting to pypi)
Checking dist/spotify_win_cli-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl: FAILED
ERROR    `long_description` has syntax errors in markup and would not be        
     rendered on PyPI.                                                      
     No content rendered from RST source.                                   
WARNING  `long_description_content_type` missing. defaulting to `text/x-rst`.   
Checking dist/spotify-win-cli-3.0.0.tar.gz: PASSED with warnings
WARNING  `long_description_content_type` missing. defaulting to `text/x-rst`.   
WARNING  `long_description` missing. 

I understand this error sort of, but when I add long_description to setup.py I get a different, (sort of) contradictory error
/tmp/build-env-2dibqg83/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py:76: _MissingDynamic: `readme` defined outside of `pyproject.toml` is ignored.
    !!

    ********************************************************************************
    The following seems to be defined outside of `pyproject.toml`:

    `readme = 'dynamic'`

    According to the spec (see the link below), however, setuptools CANNOT
    consider this value unless `readme` is listed as `dynamic`.

    https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/pyproject-toml/#declaring-project-metadata-the-project-table

    To prevent this problem, you can list `readme` under `dynamic` or alternatively
    remove the `[project]` table from your file and rely entirely on other means of
    configuration.
    ********************************************************************************

    !!

or, this error, if I try to define it, instead of leaving it dynamic. However, the coming up error tells me to set it as dynamic. There has to be something I'm missing.
        The following seems to be defined outside of `pyproject.toml`:

    `readme = "\nspotify-win-cli is a command-line tool that allows users to interact with Spotify's API seamlessly. With spotify-win-cli, users can perform a variety of tasks, including searching for tracks, albums, and artists, creating and managing playlists, and even controlling playback directly from the terminal.\n\nKey Features:\n- Search: Easily search for tracks, albums, and artists using simple commands.\n- Playlist Management: Create, delete, and manage your Spotify playlists effortlessly.\n- Playback Control: Control playback of your favorite tracks without leaving the terminal.\n- Integration: Seamlessly integrates with your existing Spotify account, providing access to all your playlists and saved tracks.\n\nInstallation:\nYou can install spotify-win-cli via pip:\n"`

    According to the spec (see the link below), however, setuptools CANNOT
    consider this value unless `readme` is listed as `dynamic`.

    https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/pyproject-toml/#declaring-project-metadata-the-project-table

    To prevent this problem, you can list `readme` under `dynamic` or alternatively
    remove the `[project]` table from your file and rely entirely on other means of
    configuration.

which is making me confused. This is my first time trying to upload a package to PyPi, and so far it's been like pulling teeth, which is making me feel like I'm not doing something right. Anyways, any help appreciated. Also if you find any other errors in pyproject.toml, please don't hesitate to tell. Thanks a BUNCH.

In your pyproject.toml you have readme = "dynamic". You should remove this line and instead write dynamic = ["readme"]. This is how you list the metadata fields that are dynamic.
